# django multiple related_name() search filter

Tags: django

I have a profile.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(class)s", unique=True)
    providers = models.ManyToManyField(ServiceProvider, related_name="%(class)s")

class ServiceProvider(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, default="ims")
```

How do I get to the user object with just having the profile object.
Can I do: (assuming I have my service provider object)

```
provider.userprofile.user.get() // or something like that.
```

I'd like to do that in one sql query. So if I had just the pk of the provider, it would be great to get to the user profile and/or the user that holds that provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your User is just a foreign key, all you need is `provider.userprofile.user`

If you don't want that to incur a second SQL query, you can just use the `select_related` option when selecting your profile, like:

```
UserProfile.objects.get(pk=<the_id>,select_related=True)
```

As written, your models don't provide a trivial way to get from the provider to the User, since there is a ManyToMany from the `ServiceProvider` to the `UserProfile`.  You'll have to get the set of `UserProfile`s associated with the provider, get the one you want, and then proceed to get the User as above.